# Execute Python function on remote machine

Tags: python, function, python-2.7

I have a requirement where I need to execute Python (version 2.7) function on remote machine. I am able to execute it locally by using following on windows command prompt. Python file is present in test folder on d drive.

```
"d:\python27\ipy.exe" -c "import sys; sys.path.append('d:\\test'); import py1;py1.Multiply(5,100)"
```

I tried similar way to execute this function on remote machine but giving error “File –c does not exist”. Py1 is present in shared folder and python exe is also present in another shared folder.

```
"\\Remotemachinename\python\ipy64.exe" –c "import sys; sys.path.append(‘\\Remotemachinename\Shared’); import py1;py1.Multiply(5,100)"
```

Below is the script content.

```
import sys
def Multiply(a,b):  
print(a*b)
```

Please provide any pointers to run this.

Comment: Try `sys.path.append('\\\\Remotemachinename\\Shared');` instead of what you have in your question.

Comment: Tried but getting same error

Comment: Make sure you use `'` (apostrophes) and not the `‘` and `’` characters which you have for some reason in your question.

Comment: I am using (apostrophes) only. it might be copy paste error in question.

Comment: If it's your question then you should know why the apostrophes are messed up (and fix them). It's possible the problem is you're trying to execute a program installed on another machine locally — and from the looks of it, the local machine might have a different processor architecture than the remote one does.